# How to prove the below differential equation has no real solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

|dy/dx|+|y|+1=0

I have no idea how to use proof by contradiction!
Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first two terms on the left are at least zero. So if there were a $y$ that satisfies this equation, it would give you that something that is at least $1$ is equal to zero, which is nonsense.

Comment: Can you explain more why it is zero?  I am new to proof by contradiction and the subject of differential equation! I

Comment: $|f(x)| \ge 0$ is what they mean which means of there was a y that satisfies for when the first two terms are zero it would yield a nonsense equality

Comment: Simply because the absolute value of a number is always positive.

Comment: @Kaynex: I think you mean non-negative. It can certainly be $0$.

Comment: You mean that the positive value of |dy/dx|+|y| can never be equal to -1!